# Difference between dependent and correlated variables

Tags: correlation, independence

I read that correlated variables are always dependent but dependent variables may be uncorrelated. Can anyone please correct me if I am wrong? And also explain me intuitively the difference between correlation and dependence in variables with an example? I will be very thankful

Comment: Thank you @kjetilbhalvorsen, but I am looking for more of an intuitive explanation. If you have checked the link that you have mentioned here, it does a very good job but, apologies, I couldn't derive an intuitive explanation from it. Please help if you can elaborate more on the answer

Comment: There are more intuitive explanations at some of the other duplicates. See also some of the discussions in answers and some comments in posts under "Related" in the sidebar

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that X ranges from -2 to +2.  Suppose that Y = X^2.

Now the correlation will be close to 0 (how close depends on how noisy the data are) but the dependence will be strong.